# Sumif with 3 criteria's from a date by name get cost

Tags: sumifs

I have an issue with getting some information on a data sheet, I have done a formula based on lots of other one I use and I am getting the error "to many arguments", my formula is:

=SUMIF(Invoicing Sheet[Week Start],">=1/8/22",InvoicingSheet[Name],"Albert Johnson", Invoicing Sheet[Shadowing Cost])

I need the total shadowing cost for Albert during the period 1/8/22 to present, I have tried various version but no success, can anyone help please.